# UIWebView would not load

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I am trying to create a `UIWebView` but it would not load.

I just get empty frame

```
func webViewDidStartLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    let url = NSURL (string: "http://www.sourcefreeze.com");
    let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!);
    webview.loadRequest(requestObj);
}
```

Comment: That method will never be called

Comment: You need to load your page out of that method. Inside a button action or viewDidLoad method

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33179698/how-to-embed-a-youtube-video-into-my-app/33180958#33180958

Comment: if i put in viewdidload its crash

Comment: Edit your question and add your code

Answer (score 0):

Need more information of your question, just a guest, you are running on iOS 9, and your url is http, because of the security enhancement of iOS 9, by default, only https request is allowed, so if you want to make http request, you need to add some configuration in your info.plist file.

Either to add white list or allow all http request:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
```

put this inside your info.plist