# Play YouTube or Vimeo Video on iOS fullscreen and without WebView

Tags: ios, youtube, fullscreen

I know there are various libraries and approaches to play Youtube or Vimeo videos on iOS inside WebViews. Is there a way to play such a video without the use of a WebView at all? All I want to do is have my own "show video" button and when it's pressed then the default fullscreen video player on iOS should open and play the video from YouTube or Vimeo. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can try with 
https://github.com/0xced/XCDYouTubeKit
as reported in this thread:

[How to embed a Youtube video into my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33179698/how-to-embed-a-youtube-video-into-my-app)