# Youtube video view in swift

Tags: swift, webview, youtube-api

Is there a way to present youtube videos in app other than using webView, I've tried YoutubePlayer_in_WKWebView and hasn't been working. webView works but I just want the video to be displayed, not the whole page.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to obtain the actual video file if you want just the video to display without the rest of the YouTube page. While officially it's unethical to rip videos from YT, unofficially it's not that hard.

Comment: the YoutubePlayer_in_WKWebView does exactly what I need it to do, only when I press play it says "An error occurred. please try again" do you have any idea why?

Comment: What happens when you open the YT URL in a normal web browser? That error is usually an issue with the video itself.

Comment: It plays fine, but with this pod you load with the video ID and not the URL itself

Comment: it also loads fine with URL in a webView

Comment: Then it's likely an issue with the pod itself. Frankly, I would use caution with YT pods because some of them teeter on YT TOS violations. Read the third answer in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33179698/how-to-embed-a-youtube-video-into-my-app