# Error while playing You Tube videos in IOS Swift app

Tags: ios, swift, youtube

My following code plays the "fox village.mp4" video, which is commented out, but not the you tube link and gives this error:
AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id  F8BB1C28-BAE8-11D6-9C31-00039315CD46

Please help if you can. Thanks!!

```
    let videoURL = URL(string: "https://youtu.be/MTNCcC_H3oM")!


    //   let videoURL = URL(string: "https://wolverine.raywenderlich.com/content/ios/tutorials/video_streaming/foxVillage.mp4")!

    let player =  AVPlayer(url: videoURL)


    let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
    playerViewController.player = player

    present(playerViewController, animated: true) {
      player.play()
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to clear that `AVPlayer` does not have the capacity to play youtube video from `URL`.

## Note:

One thing you need to keep in your mind, `AVPlayer` is able played video if `URL` is direct downloadable.

In your case, you need to go with below solutions

## Solution: 1

To play a youtube video, You need to go with the `WKWebView` or `WKWebView` with `iFrame`

## OR

I suggest you need to go with [YTPlayerView](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper)

## OR

[How to embed a Youtube video into my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33179698/how-to-embed-a-youtube-video-into-my-app)